# What would you call this art-style?

Tags: style, art

I need to find more references to similar art-style as shown below but I can't find a good term for this look.
"Monochrome, Noir, Grunge" only yields so many results. Much appreciated!

[image]

As seen here: https://vimeo.com/55327164

Another example, though somewhat different:

[image]

Comment: The top image is not grunge, look at that clean typography. Perhaps you can ask the author on vimeo? The bottom one is different, that could be grunge. I don't think there's a more specific name that fits both images, they're not the same style.

Comment: Julio... I call it Julio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a complex topic, and it might not have an answer.

One thing is to separate the elements (black and white, grudge texture) but another thing is to put them in context.

Probably one root of this style is the initial credits on David Fincher's movie Se7en. And it is not one specific element, but the overall usage of different elements.

You can have a newspaper image, but combine it with a grudge texture, change the tone to black and white to make it old, put an old film light leak, and typography that looks like a kidnap ransom note, assemble them in a montage and you have a **psychological thriller motion graphics**.

But it is hard to define as a style.

Comment: much appreciated